# LXC Profile custom changes are being ignored during container instantiation

Tags: ssh, lxc, lxd

I need all my containers to automatically upgrade packages, install build-essential and load an ssh key I can use to ssh inside of my container immediately after launching. However even after custom changing my profile and launching a new container using said upgraded profile, none of the features were properly loaded. No ssh key to ssh inside, and no package upgrades. What am I doing wrong?

My profile looks like this:

```
config:
  user.user-data: |
    #cloud-config
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - <key>
    package_update: true
    packages:
      - build-essential
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    network: lxdbr0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    type: disk
name: production
used_by:
- /1.0/instances/server
```

Container start up command:

```
lxc launch --profile production images:ubuntu/focal server
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and lxc 4.23

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem a couple of years ago when I was automating the installs using cloud-init as you are above.

The problem is that the image 'ubuntu/focal' doesn't include the cloud-init package which means your user-data is being ignored.

The fix is to use a 'cloud' variant of the image e.g. ubuntu/focal/cloud.

e.g.

```
lxc launch --profile production images:ubuntu/focal/cloud server
```

As I'm sure your aware you can then check the progress of cloud-init in your new instance using `cloud-init status` and the logs will be in /var/log with a cloud-init prefix.

Comment: Thanks, you save me!